# Reading from NetworkStream. Which is better ReadLine() vs. Read into ByteArray?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, stream

I am using TcpClient to communicate with a server that sends information in form of "\n" delimited strings. The data flow is pretty high and once the channel is set, the stream would always have information to read from. The messages can be of variable sizes.

My question now is, would it be better to use ReadLine() method to read the messages from the stream as they are already "\n" delimited, or will it be advisable to read byteArray of some fixed size and pick up message strings from them using Split("\n") or such? (Yes, I do understand that there may be cases when the byte array gets only a part of the message, and we would have to implement logic for that too.)

Points that need to be considered here are:

- Performance.
- Data Loss. Will some data be lost if the client isn't reading as fast as the data is coming in?
- Multi-Threaded setup. What if this setup has to be implemented in a multi-threaded environment, where each thread would have a separate communication channel, however would share the same resources on the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Performance is your main concern then I would prefer the `Read` over `ReadLine` method.  I/O is one of the slower things a program can do so you want to minimize the amount of time in I/O routines by reading as much data up front.

Data loss is not really a concern here if you are using TCP.  The TCP protocol guarantees delivery and will deal with congestion issues that result in lost packets.

For the threading portion of the question we're going to need a bit more information.  What resources are shared, are they sharing `TcpClient`'s, etc ...

Comment: thanks for the help. Yes, performance is a major concern, but do you think, reading into byteArray, converting to string, checking for partial message and splitting messages wouldn't be an extra overhead and would still perform better?

Comment: With shared resources, the concern is basically the memory space on the client machine.

Comment: @Danish, a bit of string manipulation is almost certainly faster than multiple IO calls.

Answer (score 0):

I would say to go with a pool of buffers and doing reads manually (Read() on the socket), if you need a lot of performance. Pooling the buffers would avoid generating garbage, as I believe ReadLine() will generate some.

Since you're usint TCP, data loss should not be a problem.

In the multi-threaded setup, you will have to be specific, but in general, resource sharing is troublesome as it might generate a data race.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however I'm a little unclear on how do you recommend using Pool of buffers, can u elaborate a little more on it, a sample code snippet would be just great.. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a [BufferedStream](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/10/21/Increasing-NetworkStream-performance-using-a-BufferedStream-_2D00_-Demo-_2B00_-Figures.aspx) to ensure you are reading optimally out of the stream:

```
var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
using(var resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
using(var stream = resp.GetResponseStream())
using(var bufferedStream = new BufferedStream(stream))
using(var streamReader = new StreamReader(bufferedStream))
{
    while(!streamReader.EndOfStream)
    {
        string currentLine = streamReader.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(currentLine);
    }
}
```

Of course, if you're looking to scale, going async would be a necessity. As such, `ReadLine` is out of the question and you're back to byte array manipulations.

Comment: I dont think using BufferedStream would suit my requirements. As I mentioned earlier, the network stream would have a high flow of incoming datapackets, and it wouldnt terminate unless the client sends a terminate the request. Using BufferedStream would mean blocking infinitely to read all the incoming data into it first which isnt feasible here.

Comment: As far as I understand, a BufferedStream simply ensures that reads of the incoming data occur in buffer sized chunks rather than at the rate at which you are requesting it. For instance, if you are reading data from the stream in sizes smaller than the stream's buffer size, then you are reading inefficiently. Buffered stream fixes this by aligning reads to buffer size. As such it's never going to hold much more than a buffer's worth of data, but will make your reads more efficient. It won't buffer the whole stream.

Comment: Well, even I had similar thoughts, but when I tried implementing it by setting a buffer size, it resulted in an error "seek is not supported by the stream". If I didn't set a buffer size, it kept waiting indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

I would read into a byte array.... only downside: limited size. You'd need to know a certain byte amount limit, or flush the byte array into a byte collection manually sometimes, and then transform the collection back into an array of bytes, also transforming it to a string using bitConverter and finally splitting it into the real messages :p

You will have a lot of overhead flushing the array into a collection... BUT, flushing into a string would require more resources, as bytes have to be decoded AS you flush them into the string.... so it's up to you... you can choose simplicity with string or efficiency with bytes, either way it wouldnt exactly be a serious performance boost from each other, but i'd personally go with the byte collection to avoid the implicit byte conversion.

Important: This comes from personal experience from previous TCP socket usage (Quake RCON stuff), not any book or anything :) Correct me if im mistaken please.

Comment: I think, I'd read a byte array of 2048 size, convert it to a string and then split it to individual message strings. Using byte Collection would add more complexity without much gain IMHO.. Thanks for the help BTW.